# Laravel 4.2: How can i save data with priority condition?

Tags: php, laravel

Example:

```
input1 = 1;
input2 = 0;
```

if input 1 is equals to 1 then set to "last" priority saving and then,
if the input 2 is equals to 0 then set to "first" priority saving.

Comment: Please explain more ?

Comment: Provide further information about the use case.

Comment: @fan sir, I have input named `item_quantity[]` and I could duplicate that input using javascript, then after cloning that input sometimes user inputted. 
`item_quantity[0] = 1;`
`item_quantity[1] = 0;`
then and i just want to save first the 0 value before 1.

Comment: Hi @Kent . Have you try to use if condition instead?  Can you show more code?

Comment: @Kent Malaki ba ang anes mo?  Patingin naman ng buto mo ?

Comment: @Jonjie bakit? gusto mo ba kainin?

Comment: @Kent Ipakain ko sana sa nagtitinda ng manok sa labas. `if(input1 == 1)`

Answer (score 0):

You could use plain old PHP array_unshift(). It pushes to beginning of array.

For example:

```
$item_quantity = array();
foreach($inputs as $input) {
    if($input->priority === 0) {  // Your condition here
        array_unshift($item_quantity, $input);
    } else {
        $item_quantity[] = $input;
    }
}
```